# Define operator = with std::string

Tags: c++, operators, assignment-operator

Good morning! I'm trying to define the assignment operator for a class like this:

```
Person {
string name;int age;
Person(string name,int age);
}
```

I know that if name would be a char*, I've first to delete the previous version of name, make it NULL and allocate a new array of char.
Now I've a string, so what I've to do? 
I thought to write something like this:

```
Person(const Person& copy){
this->name=copy.name;
this->age=copy.age; }
```

but it doesn't work. I tried to delete the string name, but the compiler gives me an error.
Where is the problem? Thank you!

Comment: You don't need a copy constructor or assignment operator.  They will be generated for you.  This is a main benifit of using RAII types.

Comment: Your don't need to use the `this->` syntax to access members.  Access them directly.  Usually the `this->` is only used to differentiate between members and parameters that are the same name (I usually name them differently).

Comment: @NathanOliver I know but it's possible that I need a different behavior.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thank you, I know, I use it only because I used to do that in Java.

Comment: @user2993413 Then you should include that.  As is you are fine only specifying a constructor.

Comment: Why I have to define a constructor? I've not understand.. If I need a particular behaviour when I copy a Person, for example copy only the name, I need only to define the copy constructor without the field age. Is it right? I don't need another constructor of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Person(const Person& copy){
```

is a copy constructor, if you want assignment operator then use;

```
Person& operator=(const Person& rop) {
   name=rop.name;
   age=rop.age;
   return *this;
}
```

But the compiler with synthesize a copy-assignment operator if the class does not define one - the same applies to copy constructor. So its unclear to me where is your problem.

You are right that if you have a `char*` which is assigned buffer from dynamic allocation, then you must manage its lifetime yourself (or using smart pointer). But with std::string or any other class which uses [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom, you use the so called [rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), so no need to worry about writing code to make copies.

Comment: Sorry, I've pasted the wrong code. I wrote the same, thank you very much.
Meanwhile, I saw that there's a big difference writing
inline 'Person p = otherPerson;'
and
inline 'Person p;
p = otherPerson'
<br>(I don't know if I wrote correctly for code in comment..).
What's the difference? The first is a copy, instead the second is an assignment on a pre-existing object?

Comment: @user2993413 'Person p = otherPerson;'  requires copy constructor, and 'Person p; p = otherPerson' assignment operator. Copy constructor is used when copy initializing variable (As in your example), when calling a function with variable passed by value, when returning a variable from function - also by value.

Comment: I tried to modify my copy constructor deleting the age. Then I execute this code: `Person p("andrea",23);
Person c(p);
Person d =p`
I thought that would be c.age=(random) and d.age=23, while the result is c.age=0 and d.age=(random). Why?

Comment: @user2993413 if you dont initialize age in copy constructor then it will be default initialized - its value will be indeterminate (random). c.age and d.age both should be indeterminate, but that means it might be also 0. In both places you called copy constructor here.

Comment: Also in d? I thought that it was not dependent on the copy constructor! In the operator= definition I've set the age. Why it "doesn't see" that assignment?

Comment: `Person d =p` uses copy initialization (copy constructor), `Person d; d = p;` will use `operator=` but only for `d=p;` You can rewrite `d=p;` as `d.operator=(p);`

Answer (score 1):

That is not an assignment operator. Rather, its a Copy Constructor.
You define your Copy assignment operator like this:

```
Person& operator = (const Person& other)
{
    name= other.name;
    age=  other.age;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know that if name would be a char*, I've first to delete the previous version of name, make it NULL and allocate a new array of char

Assuming the class "owns" the pointed array, that is correct.

> Now I've a string, so what I've to do?

In the copy assignment operator, you will need to copy assign the member string just like you do with the int.

That's exactly what the implicit, compiler generated copy assignment operator does, so you don't need to declare one yourself at all.

> I thought to write something like this:

```
Person(const Person& copy)
```

That's a copy constructor. You don't need to declare that either, because the implicitly generated one does exactly what you want.

> but the compiler gives me an error. Where is the problem?

The problem will be in the location indicated by the error message.

---

TL;DR you don't need to add a custom copy assignment, nor copy constructor at all.

Comment: I know that in this particular case I don't need it, but if I would need to copy only the name without the age I need to define it. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user2993413 sure, if you want to do something other than what the implicit copy assignment does, then you need to define a custom one yourself. If you want to do what the implicit copy assignment does, then you don't need to declare it yourself.

Comment: Ok thank you! I don't need it only when I want the default behavior.